# Inputting integers into a Java array list

Tags: java, arrays

Currently I have managed to be able to input values into my array list, however whenever they are printed in my program, the old values duplicate whenever a new one is inputted.  So far I have this, and I really hope someone can help show me where I am going wrong with this.  Thankyou!

```
    markList.add(Integer.parseInt(markInput.getText()));
    for (Integer number : markList) {
        sb.append(number != null ? number.toString() : "");
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    markOutput.setText(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Can you list the whole class? I'd say that you are reusing the sb object, so, that you're always appending (sb.append()) elements to the sb that already contains old elements.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Please explain this code, and create and post a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

try setting clearing the StringBuilder before adding the new values

e.g.

```
sb = new StringBuilder ();
```

Comment: That was a really easy fix.  Thankyou very much for the help, as I didn't know that setting that same thing as global would have such a drastic effect.

Comment: The real solution is probably to make `sb` local.

Comment: `probably` - but based upon the small amount of code - who knows, but probably